# Propagate values in pandas for missing dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe for business days

```
In [23]: d = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['20070105', '20070105', '20070106', '20070106', '20070106', '20070109'], 's' : [1, 2, 1,2,3,1], 'i': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a']})
In [26]: d['date'] = pd.to_datetime(d['date'], format='%Y%m%d')
In [27]: d
Out[27]: 
        date  i  s
0 2007-01-05  a  1
1 2007-01-05  b  2
2 2007-01-06  a  1
3 2007-01-06  b  2
4 2007-01-06  c  3
5 2007-01-09  a  1
```

I want to fill in the data for missing dates (according to 'alldays' calendar) and the output should be as follows. Basically 20070107 and 20070108 were missing and its data was copied from 20070106.

```
Out[31]: 
         date  i  s
0  2007-01-05  a  1
1  2007-01-05  b  2
2  2007-01-06  a  1
3  2007-01-06  b  2
4  2007-01-06  c  3
5  2007-01-07  a  1
6  2007-01-07  b  2
7  2007-01-07  c  3
8  2007-01-08  a  1
9  2007-01-08  b  2
10 2007-01-08  c  3
11 2007-01-09  a  1
```

What is the best way to do this in pandas?

Comment: Please read [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and edit your post correspondingly. Use dates instead of strings in your input and output data sets

Comment: Thanks. Added reproducible code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

- [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for unique `MultiIndex`
- reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) for unique `DatetimeIndex`
- [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by minimal and maximal values in index, add missing values by `method='ffill'`
- reshape back by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)
- last remove second level of `MultiIndex` and convert `Datetimeindex` to column

---

```
df = (
      d.set_index(['date', d.groupby('date').cumcount()])
        .unstack()
        .reindex(pd.date_range(d['date'].min(), d['date'].max()), method='ffill')
        .stack()
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .rename_axis('date')
        .reset_index()
       )
print (df)

         date  i    s
0  2007-01-05  a  1.0
1  2007-01-05  b  2.0
2  2007-01-06  a  1.0
3  2007-01-06  b  2.0
4  2007-01-06  c  3.0
5  2007-01-07  a  1.0
6  2007-01-07  b  2.0
7  2007-01-07  c  3.0
8  2007-01-08  a  1.0
9  2007-01-08  b  2.0
10 2007-01-08  c  3.0
11 2007-01-09  a  1.0
```

Comment: This is not working for me. I've now updated my example with proper sample code so that the question is clear.

Comment: Check edited answer, is necessary add `date` to `set_index` function only.

Comment: @Very nice and generic solution ! +1

Comment: @MaxU - Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful. I guess we need to the following as well to get the exact 'date' column.  reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'date'})

Comment: Glad can help! Nice day!